# iOS rangeOfString can't locate the string that is definitely there

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa

I am writing code in objective-c. I would like to extract a url from a string.

Here is my code:

```
NSMutableString *oneContent = [[latestPosts objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"content"];
NSLog(@"%@", oneContent);//no problem
NSString *string = @"http";
if ([oneContent rangeOfString:string].location == NSNotFound) {
   NSLog(@"string does not contain substring");
} else {
   NSLog(@"string contains substring!");
}
```

As you can see, I want to extract a url from the `oneContent` string, and I have checked that `oneContent` definitely contains "http", but why does the result show nothing?

Is there some better way to extract the url?

Comment: you can try like this [oneContent componentsSeparatedByString:@"stringtoseparate"]. this will return an array of separated strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `oneContent` or the actual code you are running.

This works:

```
NSMutableString *oneContent = [@"asdhttpqwe" mutableCopy];
NSLog(@"%@", oneContent);//no problem
NSString *string = @"http";
if ([oneContent rangeOfString:string].location == NSNotFound) {
   NSLog(@"string does not contain substring");
} else {
   NSLog(@"string contains substring!");
}
```

NSLog output:

```
Untitled[5911:707] asdhttpqwe
Untitled[5911:707] string contains substring!
```

It is probably best **not** to use a Mutable string unless there is some substantial reason to do so.

I would suggest using NSScanner.

Comment: And to possibly match the case a bit better, I tried NSMutableString *oneContent = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"h t t p ://thisisastring.com"] mutableCopy]; and that worked as well. (I had to add spaces because SO was converting the link text to a link.)

Comment: Thanks, man. The string originally was not mutable string, I changed according to a tutorial, but still didn't work. Now I extend my keywords, wish it to be more accurate, and it works! I don't know why, still, thanks very much.